# CodeDom How to create a method with void return type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-generation, codedom

```
public void CreateMethod()
{
    CodeMemberMethod mymethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
    mymethod.Name = testMethod;
    CodeTypeReference ctr = new CodeTypeReference();
    //Assign the return type to the method.
    mymethod.ReturnType = ctr;

    CodeSnippetExpression snippet1 = new CodeSnippetExpression("AutomationBase obj = new AutomationBase()");
    CodeSnippetExpression snippet2 = new CodeSnippetExpression("obj.Execute(testCases[1])");       
    CodeExpressionStatement stmt1 = new CodeExpressionStatement(snippet1);
    CodeExpressionStatement stmt2 = new CodeExpressionStatement(snippet2);
    mymethod.Statements.Add(stmt1);
    mymethod.Statements.Add(stmt2);
    mymethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
    myclass.Members.Add(mymethod);
}
```

output

```
 public virtual void TestCaseId002() {
            AutomationBase obj = new AutomationBase();
            obj.Execute(testCases[1]);
        }
```

getting **virtual void**

i only need void.

Comment: `virtual` has nothing to do with return types.

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't even compile due to `ctr.;`. Please provide a [mcve] (It's not clear what this has to do with ASP.NET, either...)

Comment: but by default c# methods are non virtual.

Comment: @jon its just one edit change

Comment: but CodeDom (tries) to be language agnostic. Just because C# has certain rules, it doesn't mean that CodeDom does.

Comment: @Damien  yeah i agree, but my requirement is to generate public void method. how can i accomplish that

Comment: That still isn't a [mcve] though. We can't copy, paste, compile and run your code - and the extra `.` suggests that it may have been typed in separately from the actual code that is failing. (Otherwise, how did the typo get in there?)

Answer (score 6):

You need to mark the method as `Final`, to indicate that it's not inheritable:

```
mymethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
```

Comment: I have one more doubt how can we specify the location where we need the code to be generated?